SAM template: AWS Lambda Environment Variable
This is my required environment variable for a lambda function
AuthFlowsParams: '{"policyName": "b2c","tenantId": "d2b2","jwkHost": "dtui","jwkParamStoreName": "/JwkSignInFlow"}'

how to create above environment variable using below mappings
AuthPolicyName: b2c
AuthTenantId: d2b2
AuthJwkHost: dtui
AuthJwkParamStoreName: /JwkSignInFlow

Is it possible to construct a environment variable using the mappings as above ?

Sorry, but it is unclear what you are asking for. Are you saying that you want to set the JSON-like string as an Environment variable on an AWS Lambda function? Will this be a static value (never changing), or will it change with each invocation? Where do these values come from? More information, please.
